# Python import function from another file via argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm writing a small utility function which takes in input arguments of the location of a Python file, and also a function to call within the Python file

For example `src/path/to/file_a.py`

```
def foo():
  ...
```

In the utility function, I'm parsing the arguments like so:

```
python ./util.py --path src/path/to/file_a.py --function foo
```

and the `foo` function needs to be used later in the `util.py` in another library:

```
def compile():
  compiler.compile(
    function=foo,
    etc
  )
```

What's the best way of importing the `foo` function via argparse?

---

Some initial thoughts:

`util.py`:

```
def get_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--path", type=str)
  parser.add_argument("--function", type=str)
  return parser.parse_args()

def compile(path, function):
  import path 
  compiler.compile(
    function=path.function,
    etc
  )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  args = get_args()
  compile(
    path=args.path
    function=args.function
  )
```

however importing via argparse, and adding it to the function does not seem to work nicely.

There's also the idea of using `sys.path.append`:

```
def compile(path, function):
  import sys
  sys.path.append(path)
```

but then I'm unsure of how to import the `foo` function from that.

Comment: State the actual error, not a vague 'does not work'.  All `arparse` can do for you is get the two strings.  What you do with the strings is not part of `argparse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be rephrased as "how do I import a python file given a path?" To do that, we can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/5666087. Here is a code example that incorporates the answer to that question with your needs.

```py
import argparse
import importlib.util
import sys


def get_function_object(path_to_pyfile: str, funcname: str):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("tmpmodulename", path_to_pyfile)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules["tmpmodulename"] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    if not hasattr(module, funcname):
        raise AttributeError(f"Cannot find function '{funcname}'in imported module")
    # TODO: Consider testing whether this object is a callable.
    return getattr(module, funcname)


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--path", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--function", type=str)
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_args()
    function = get_function_object(args.path, funcname=args.function)
    compiler.compile(function=funtion)
```